# How to get Latitude and Longitude with mapview Gesture touch in IOS with swift

Tags: ios, swift, mkmapview, swift3

My name is Tony dhand. I'm new in IOS development. Currently, I'm working on `Mkmapview`. Now I'm facing some problems.

My task is to display users current location(I had complete this). Next is when the user scrolls the map and long press add a marker on that place and get the **Latitude** and **Longitude**. And also get the distance between two locations.  Here is my code:

```
import UIKit
import MapKit

import CoreLocation

class ViewController: UIViewController ,MKMapViewDelegate , CLLocationManagerDelegate{

    let corelocationmanager = CLLocationManager()
    private var mapChangedFromUserInteraction = false

    @IBOutlet weak var mapview: MKMapView!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()

        if (CLLocationManager.locationServicesEnabled()){
            self.corelocationmanager.requestAlwaysAuthorization();         self.corelocationmanager.delegate = self
            self.corelocationmanager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
            self.corelocationmanager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
            self.corelocationmanager.startUpdatingLocation()
            self.corelocationmanager.distanceFilter = kCLDistanceFilterNone;
            let coord = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(37, -122)
            let span = MKCoordinateSpanMake(1, 1)
            mapview.region = MKCoordinateRegionMake(coord, span)
            self.view.addSubview(mapview)


            // self.mapview.sh; owsUserLocation = true

        }else{
            //   location service is disable
        }
        mapview.delegate = self;
        mapview.isUserInteractionEnabled = true;


        let theSpan:MKCoordinateSpan = MKCoordinateSpanMake(0.01 , 0.01)
        let location:CLLocationCoordinate2D = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 45.612125, longitude: 22.948280)
        let theRegion:MKCoordinateRegion = MKCoordinateRegionMake(location, theSpan)

        mapview.setRegion(theRegion, animated: true)

        var anotation = MKPointAnnotation()
        anotation.coordinate = location
        anotation.title = "The Location"
        anotation.subtitle = "This is the location !!!"
        mapview.addAnnotation(anotation)

        let longPress = UILongPressGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "action:")
        longPress.minimumPressDuration = 1.0
        // mapview.addGestureRecognizer(longPress)

        setCenterForMap()


    }

    func setCenterForMap() {
        var mapRect: MKMapRect = MKMapRectNull
        for loc in mapview.annotations {
            let point: MKMapPoint = MKMapPointForCoordinate(loc.coordinate)
            print( "location is : \(loc.coordinate)");
            mapRect = MKMapRectUnion(mapRect, MKMapRectMake(point.x,point.y,0,0))
        }
        if (corelocationmanager.location != nil) {
            let point: MKMapPoint = MKMapPointForCoordinate(corelocationmanager.location!.coordinate)
            print( "Cur location is : \(corelocationmanager.location!.coordinate)");
            mapRect = MKMapRectUnion(mapRect, MKMapRectMake(point.x,point.y,0,0))
        }

        mapview.setVisibleMapRect(mapRect, edgePadding: UIEdgeInsetsMake(40.0, 40.0, 40.0, 40.0), animated: true)

    }

    func action(gestureRecognizer:UIGestureRecognizer) {

        var touchPoint = gestureRecognizer.location(in: self.mapview)
        var newCoord:CLLocationCoordinate2D = mapview.convert(touchPoint, toCoordinateFrom: self.mapview)

        var newAnotation = MKPointAnnotation()
        newAnotation.coordinate = newCoord
        newAnotation.title = "New Location"
        newAnotation.subtitle = "New Subtitle"
        mapview.addAnnotation(newAnotation)

    }

    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
        let location = locations.last
        let center = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: location!.coordinate.latitude, longitude: (location?.coordinate.longitude)!)

        let region = MKCoordinateRegion(center: center, span: MKCoordinateSpan(latitudeDelta: 1, longitudeDelta: 1))

        self.mapview.setRegion(region, animated: true)
        self.corelocationmanager.stopUpdatingLocation()

        //   let locValue:CLLocationCoordinate2D = manager.location!.coordinate
        //   print("locations = \(locValue.latitude) \(locValue.longitude)")





        CLGeocoder().reverseGeocodeLocation(manager.location!, completionHandler: {(placemarks, error)->Void in
            if (error != nil) {
                print("Reverse geocoder failed with error" + (error?.localizedDescription)!)
                return
            }

            if (placemarks?.count)! > 0 {
                let pm = (placemarks?[0])! as CLPlacemark
                self.displayLocationInfo(placemark: pm)
            } else {
                print("Problem with the data received from geocoder")
            }
        })


    }



    func coordinateRegionForCoordinates(coords: [CLLocationCoordinate2D]) -> MKCoordinateRegion {
        var rect: MKMapRect = MKMapRectNull
        for coord in coords {
            let point: MKMapPoint = MKMapPointForCoordinate(coord)
            rect = MKMapRectUnion(rect, MKMapRectMake(point.x, point.y, 0, 0))
        }
        return MKCoordinateRegionForMapRect(rect)
    }        

    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didFailWithError error: Error) {
        print("Error:", error.localizedDescription)
    }

    func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager!, didUpdateLocations locations: [AnyObject]!) {
        CLGeocoder().reverseGeocodeLocation(manager.location!, completionHandler: {(placemarks, error)->Void in
            if (error != nil) {
                print("Reverse geocoder failed with error" + (error?.localizedDescription)!)
                return
            }

            if (placemarks?.count)! > 0 {
                let pm = (placemarks?[1])! as CLPlacemark
                self.displayLocationInfo(placemark: pm)
            } else {
                print("Problem with the data received from geocoder")
            }
        })
    }

    func displayLocationInfo(placemark: CLPlacemark) {
        if placemark != nil {
            //stop updating location to save battery life
            corelocationmanager.stopUpdatingLocation()
            print(placemark.locality!)
            print(placemark.postalCode!)
            print(placemark.administrativeArea!)

        }
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


    private func mapViewRegionDidChangeFromUserInteraction() -> Bool {
        let view = self.mapview.subviews[0]
        //  Look through gesture recognizers to determine whether this region change is from user interaction
        if let gestureRecognizers = view.gestureRecognizers {
            for recognizer in gestureRecognizers {
                if( recognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerState.began || recognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerState.ended ) {

                    print("ok")
                    return true
                }
            }
        }
        return false
    }

    func mapView(mapView: MKMapView, regionWillChangeAnimated animated: Bool) {
        mapChangedFromUserInteraction = mapViewRegionDidChangeFromUserInteraction()
        if (mapChangedFromUserInteraction) {
            // user changed map region

            print("dhand")
        }
    }

}
```

Please help thanks in advance

Comment: Strange your name doesnot match Tony dhand

Comment: Now what is your question?